# ExtJS null 'id'

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-8

I have this code

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: '100%',
    autoScroll: true,
    height: '100%',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'IMAGES',
    items: Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
        padding: 5,
        store: ImageStore,
        tpl: imageTpl
    })
});
```

and whenever I click in Panel it gives me an error (debugged in IE)

---

**Webpage error details**

*User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 etc...*

*Timestamp: Thu, 25 Aug 2011 21:15:22 UTC*

*Message: 'id' is null or not an object*

*Line: 7*

*Char: 183716*

*Code: 0*

*URI: /ext-4.0.1/ext-all.js*

---

and whenever I have a link like `<a href="#" onClick="whateverFunction();">Run</a>` it fails to run the function...

Comment: is that **all** of your code?

Comment: this is the code that gives a trouble, when I remove it it gets away

Comment: is this inside your `Ext.onReady`?

Answer (score 0):

What does the content of `imageTpl` look like? Try changing the config name from `tpl` to `itemTpl`.

Answer (score 0):

tpl should work ok, depending on what imageTpl looks like. From the code, this is the only thing that looks like it would bomb this.

Ext.panel.Panel height and width take a number, not a string ("100%"). You may also want to use Fit layout on the Panel.